# Using a custom build command for a remote environment in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I am working with a remote Linux system where I want all compilation to occur. Visual Studio does this well, but I would like to use cmake on the remote server. The CMakeList.txt I created works well when I run `cmake . && make` remotely, but I would like Visual Studio to run that command when I ask it to build on my local computer. How would I go about setting that up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My answer will be based on your question. How to set the build on Visual Studio to run the make on Linux...
First make sure you created the Makefile project as you can see in the image below:

[image: Creating a Linux Makefile Project]

Then you will be able to configure the build/rebuild and clean commands.

[image: Configuration on VS2017 - Project Properties]

This is just the starting point, but hopefully it answers your question. Good Luck!